# NSLocalizedString within an array

Tags: arrays, random, internationalization, xcode4.6

For the purpose of internationalization, I tried to put `NSLocalizedString` within an Array. I have random pics with information related to each pic. It works with english. Does not work with macro, what is wrong?

```
- (void)showimage
{
 int randomimages = arc4random() % 7+1;

 self.rahmen.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.png",randomimages]];

/*    text without the local.strings worked perferct

 self.myStrings = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
 @" info 0, nothing",
 @" info 1 english",
 @" info 2 english",
 @" info 3 english",
 @" info 4 english",
 @" info 5 english",
 @" info 6 english",
 @" inf0 7 different english",nil];
 */

//here I wanted to put the different strings for internationalzation

self.myStrings = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: NSLocalizedString
                   (@"info0",
                    @"info1",
                    @"info2",
                    @"info3",
                    @"info4",
                    @"info5",
                    @"info6",
                    @"info7",nil)
                  ];                                                 
label.text=[self.myStrings objectAtIndex:randomimages];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this might helps you

```
self.myStrings = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
    NSLocalizedString(@"info0",nil),
    NSLocalizedString(@"info1",nil),
    NSLocalizedString(@"info2",nil),
    nil];
```

Comment: (@"info0",@"yourcomment") would be fine.

Answer (score 0):

The `NSLocalizedString` macro takes two arguments: the non-localized string and a comment. That's it, nothing else, you can't magically make it return an array by caling it on an array. You have to wrap **each** non-localized string in this macro in order to achieve what you want.

Comment: Yepp, but that is my problem: localization and the random text. I know how to do it with a label or String. But in this case I go blank.

Comment: @user2369988 so are you asking for a method to shuffle an array?

Comment: no. actually I am looking for a method to internationalize my app, what precisely means to transform my method with an array and randomly text in a method with localizable strings, so my text(corresponding to each randomly chosen pic) will be displayed in different languages. Sorry that I did not explained that better. also a language problem i guess.

Comment: @user2369988 then `NSLocalizedString(array[arc4random_uniform(array.count)], nil)`

Comment: First: I do not understand how this method gets the information for the 8 pics. I would store the 8 textblocks for each language in a Localizable.String file.
second:
I do get a red flag:

int randomimages = arc4random () % 8;
    
self.rahmen.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.png",randomimages]];
self.myStrings = NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSLocalizedString(array[arc4random_uniform(array.count)], nil)]; 
 
//--- use of undeclared identifier array, I did declare an array = "myString"
     
label.text=[self.myStrings objectAtIndex:randomimages];